# Query the probability of abnormal emails

Tags: sql

Now there is a requirement where I want to calculate the probability of failed emails sent from normal users to normal users.
In my **PieCloudDB database**, I have an email table as follows:

| id | send_id | receive_id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | no_completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | no_completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 | completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 | completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | no_completed | 2023-11-01 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 | completed | 2023-11-02 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | completed | 2023-11-02 |
| 10 | 4 | 1 | completed | 2023-11-03 |
| 11 | 3 | 1 | completed | 2023-11-03 |
| 12 | 3 | 4 | completed | 2023-11-03 |

The first line indicates that user with id 4 successfully sent an email to user with id 3 on 2023-11-01. The third line indicates that user with id 1 failed to send an email to user with id 4 on 2023-11-01.

Below is a user table, is_blacklist with a value of 0 indicates a normal user, and is_blacklist with a value of 1 indicates a user on the blacklist.

| id | is_blacklist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

The first line indicates that user with id 1 is a normal user. The second line indicates that user with id 2 is not a normal user but is on the blacklist.

Now, I need to query the probability of failed emails sent from normal users to normal users for each date. The results should be rounded to 3 decimal places and sorted in ascending order by date. For the example provided, the query results would be as follows:

| date | p |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 0.333 |
| 2023-11-03 | 0.000 |

The probability of failure on 2023-11-01 is 0.333. **This is because in the 7th row of the email table, the user with id 2 is on the blacklist and should not be included in the calculation.** There were a total of 6 attempts by normal users to send emails to other normal users, but 2 of them failed. Therefore, the probability is 0.333.

For 2023-11-02, there are two rows of data, but both of them involve the blacklist user 2. Therefore, no output for that date.

On 2023-11-03, all the emails were completed. Therefore, the result is 0.000.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT date,
       ROUND(
           SUM(CASE WHEN u1.is_blacklist = 0 AND u2.is_blacklist = 0 AND e.type = 'no_completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
           SUM(CASE WHEN u1.is_blacklist = 0 AND u2.is_blacklist = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
           3
       ) AS p
FROM email e
JOIN email_user u1 ON e.send_id = u1.id
JOIN email_user u2 ON e.receive_id = u2.id
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

But I get the ERROR: "division by zero", can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the right answer, you can try the following query in your PieCloudDB Database.

```
select email.date, round(
    sum(case email.type when'completed' then 0 else 1 end)*1.0/count(email.type),3
) as p
from email
join email_user as u1 on (email.send_id=u1.id and u1.is_blacklist=0)
join email_user as u2 on (email.receive_id=u2.id and u2.is_blacklist=0)
group by email.date order by email.date;
```

Comment: Please add a description of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I test the following query in PieCloudDB Cloud on Cloud edition, it will give you the desired results.

```
select
date
,round(sum(case type when 'no_completed' then 1.0 else 0 end)/count(*), 3) p 
from email
where send_id in ( 
                    select id 
                    from email_user
                    where is_blacklist = 0
                 )
and receive_id in (
                    select id 
                    from email_user
                    where is_blacklist = 0
                  )
group by date
order by date;
```

[image]